# pyArango bulkImport_json is complaining about improper indicies

Tags: python, json, arangodb, pyarango

I'm testing the ability to store PyTest results, generated by the json plugin for that test harness, into ArangoDB.  I am attempting to import as follows

```
import pyArango.connection as adbConn
dbConn = adbConn.Connection(...)
db = dbConn['mydb']
collection = db.collections['PyTestResults']
collection.bulkImport_json('/path/to/results.json')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyArango/collection.py", line 777, in bulkImport_json
    errorMessage = "At least: %d errors. The first one is: '%s'\n\n more in <this_exception>.data" % 
(len(data), data[0]["errorMessage"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

What isn't making sense is that the JSON file is properly formed.  In fact, using the regular Python JSON module, it works just fine:

```
import json
with open('/path/to/results.json') as fd:
    data = json.load(fd)

print(data)
```

This works.  The beginning of the file is

```
{"report": 
    {"environment": 
        {
            "Python": "3.6.9", "Platform": "Linux-4.4.0-17763-Microsoft-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic"
        },
```

It seems that the library, `pyArango`, is wanting the keys to be integers.  I tried this, that is I tried changing `"report"` to `0`.  However, this resulted in invalidating the JSON structure.

How is one to use the **pyArango** library to import JSON?  The overall structure of this JSON file doesn't look much different than any of the [examples in this page](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangoimport-examples-json.html).  Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I will postpone "voting" to delete my own question a few more days as I hope someone will know the answer.  However, I have found a solution to the problem of inserting new records in JSON.  I'm using `pyArango.collection.createDocument()` and then `.save()`.  Though a solution it doesn't answer the question about bulk importation which I hope to yet resolve.

Comment: Could you please post your solution as the answer to your question?